# 1 back button to 3 different language links! (smart back button)?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i'm afraid i try to fix the impossible...

On my site i got 3 different languages all linked to a english page.
The point is i have to fix a back button to:

```
www.123.com/french-voiture
www.123.com/dutch-auto
www.123.com/english-car
```

I have to fix a script that generate automatically the right link

```
<li> <a href="www.123.com/french-car" title="Back" alt="Back">- </a></li>
<li> <a href="www.123.com/dutch-car" title="Back" alt="Back"> -</a></li>
<li> <a href="www.123.com/english-car" title="Back" alt="Back">- </a></li>
```

So i get a link to car! (english) but i can't fix the link's to the dutch and frensh language.

Is there a better way to do this or to fix this problem???

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved using JavaScript. This snippet will go back 1 page in your browsers history - returning to the page they were coming from.

`<a href="javascript:history.back();">back</a>`

Alternatively, you can use JavaScript to check the [referrer](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp), and write out a link to a different page depending on the value of your referrer. This may be useful if you don't actually just want to go back 1 page, but go to a page depending on your referrer.

Comment: <a href="javascript:history.back();">back</a> is not a option because this page will have a link to other page's. and if people find the page at google they will linked back to google not my home section!

Comment: Okay fair enough :-) In that case would the alternative I've given not work for you? Check the document.referrer property, extract from that if the user came from the FR/NL/EN page, and finally write out the correct link. Of course you will still have to account for external / google visitors; if it suits your needs you may either default them to EN, sent them to another page, or detect user locale and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions:

1. Generate the English page three times, each time with a different link. From all other (localized) pages, link to the version which has the correct "back link".
2. Save the language in the user's session and modify the HTML when the browser tries to download the English page.
3. Add all three links and send a piece of JavaScript which makes the unwanted versions invisible or removes them from the DOM.

Comment: i think option 2 and 3 are interesting can you explain them in more detail.

Comment: Those solutions are so obvious to me that I have no idea what details you might be missing. Please think of a specific question and post it as a new question here.